# Help understanding relationship between sequences and partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'll like to know the sequence a(n) associated with the following partial sum : s(n)= 1/2^n.

Firstly, i've found a(n) = -1/(2^n) (not sure if its entirely correct). Then by definition, s(1) = a(1), but s(1) = 1/2 and a(1) = -1/2.

Comment: Hint: $\;s_n = s_{n-1} + a_n\,$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Right, i've used that equation to find a(n).

Comment: @SantiagoFernandez `by definition, s(1) = a(1)` That's assuming that the sum starts at index $\,n=1\,$. In that case $a_1 = s_1 = \frac{1}{2}\,$, and $\,a_n  = s_n - s_{n-1}\,$ for $\,n \ge 2\,$.